# Detecting the Javascript method which is executed in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, dom-events, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am showing an `URL` in my `uiwebview` and it is working properly.

So the web page actually contains some Javascript functions (fun1, fun2, fun3...) which is getting executed once I select some portion over webview.

So my requirement is to detect the Javascript method which is being executed on selection over  webview.

So I have implemented `UITapGestureRecognizer` over webview.

```
[myWebView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Now once I select on the webview my following method is called:

```
-(void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

   [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getItem(){ var functionName =arguments.callee.name; alert(functionName);}getItem()"];
    
}
```

But I am not getting the Javascript method which is executed, how can I get this?

**Note :** Somewhere I have read that `arguments.callee.name;`  has been deprecated, so is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the JavaScript on the remote webpage to set a global variable with the currently running function's name, like so:

```
var CURRENT_FUNCTION = '';
function someFunction() {
    CURRENT_FUNCTION = 'someFunction()';
}
```

Then from the iOS side you can accomplish this by changing your code to say:

```
NSString *currentFunction = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return CURRENT_FUNCTION"];
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I can not change the webpage as i have not have the permission for it .It is still not working.

Comment: You will not be able to accomplish this without altering the server side JS.